# Align table element to the center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to align this table element to the center, the on containing the square but all just seems not to work. Can someone here please help me fix the burg.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>TURKEY - SUPER LIG</td>
        <td>#colspan#</td>
        <td>Tips</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Besistas  <strong style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#601C08; padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.2em; padding-top: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.2em;">-</strong> <strong style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#601C08; padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.2em; padding-top: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.2em;"></strong> Adana</td>
        <td>#colspan#</td>
        <td><strong style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:white; padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em; padding-top: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.2em; background-color: none; color: none;">1</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DENMARK - DBU POKALEN</td>
        <td>#colspan#</td>
        <td>Tips</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FC Helsingoer <strong style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#601C08; padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.2em; padding-top: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.2em;">-</strong> <strong style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#601C08; padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.2em; padding-top: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.2em;">-</strong> OB</td>
        <td>#colspan#</td>
            <td><strong style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:white; padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em; padding-top: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.2em; background-color: none; color: none;">Over 2.5</strong></td>
    </tr>
        
</tbody>
```

![image of what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImXsG.jpg)

Comment: Is this markup for a HTMLEmail?

Answer (score -1):

try using property justify-content : center,

Comment: alignitems: center, display: flex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That code didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Try this code
justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex;

Comment: This is simply wrong. You never just align-items, or you might end up losing content Above the Overflow. Either use the not so well supported `safe-center` or rather: `margin: auto;` on the child element. But that's pretty basic CSS knowledge.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:

```
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center; 
 align-items: center;
```

But, it is recommended not to use inline CSS. Because it takes longer time than usual to load.
You can just link a separate CSS file to this html file and give same class name for all the border thing. And style them at once which will apply to all of them.

Comment: Please specify which element to attach the CSS code to